# magento cleaning my category to 2000 products

Tags: magento, categories, product

After updating my category or subcategory products disappearing from it. Strange because always are just 2000 products left. Cache, indexing not helping. If this make more sense actually category disappearing from product.

Comment: please provide a little more information, such as your code or the tables

Comment: can you please tell me which table and for which part of code from where thanks

Answer (score 0):

Open your logs, there is a PHP error about **max_input_vars**.